# Stale Element Reference appears when navigating back to a page, how to write a neat code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, staleelementreferenceexception

I am automating in Java Selenium, without using Page Factory.

I have an *Add Candidate Button* element that is clicked in two tests. One is straightforward, after entering *InviteToCompany* page I click this button and proceed. However, another requires me to go past *InviteToCompany* page, but then use *Go Back Arrow* to go back to 'InviteToCompany' page and click *Add Candidate Button* again. This is when `StaleElementReferenceException` appears.

I have written such a piece of code to deal with this issue, however I am wondering, if there is a cleaner and neater way, than catching exception for second test, to proceed.

```
    public InviteToCompanyPO clickAddCandidateBtn() {
        try {
            getClickableElement(addCandidateBtn).click();
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            log.warn("StaleElementReferenceException caught, retrying...", e);
            getClickableElement(addCandidateBtn).click();
        }
        return new InviteToCompanyPO(driver);
    }
```

Before I had to write second test (the one causing staleness), this method simply looked like this:

```
    public InviteToCompanyPO clickAddCandidateBtn() {
        getClickableElement(addCandidateBtn).click();
        return new InviteToCompanyPO(driver);
    }
```

I tried writing something like this:

```
    public InviteToCompanyPO clickAddCandidateBtn() {
        wait
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(addCandidateBtn))
                .click();
        return new InviteToCompanyPO(driver);
    }
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a page factory?
Anyway, when you back to the `InviteToCompany` page and need to click `Add Candidate` Button again you will need to get that element again.
I mean to pass the locator or `By` of that element and get the `WebElement` object again with `driver.findElement()` method.
This causes by the fact that `WebElement` is actually a reference (pointer) to the actual Web Element on the page. And when you navigating from the page to other page the references to the objects on the previous page becoming invalid, Stale. When you open the previous page again it is rendered again, so you need to get the references (pointers) to elements on that page again.

Comment: No I am not using page factory.
I am using such code to add candidate, it uses 'new' everytime it visits this page:


    public ApplicationStep addCandidate(User user, UserType userType) {
        log.debug("Add candidate with the following details: {}.", user);
        new ApplyPO(driver)
                .getApplyCandidatePO()
                .clickAddCandidateBtn()
                .invite(userType)
                .fillData(user, true)
                .addCandidate();
        return this;
    }

Comment: It is not so clear how that new works.

Comment: I am not using spring, when I go back to page with this button, I create new page object, different from one that was used to procced turher when I visited that page for the first time